# Unable to set up new KVM Ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm new here, and pretty GREEN with Ubuntu server, but I have been managing to get have this running for about 2 years now without major incident until the other day. I was messing with a virtual machine from my phone in the car, kids started arguing in the back set waiting at the grocery store, and root ran this command.....

chmod 755 $(find / -type d)

Sooo, I backed up the files I needed from the VM, shut it down, undefined it, and deleted the .qcow2 and .xml files in the destination where the VM was running from  (this one runs off of a dedicated SSD, rather than the raidZ2 pool that the other one runs off of. I updated the server, then rebooted it, and it came back up, the other VM's are good, now I just need to get my VM back up and running, but am getting errors.

BELOW is the code I am using to setup the VM.

```
    sudo ubuntu-vm-builder kvm trusty \
 --domain xxxxxx \
 --dest /mnt/Storage/Virtual_Machines/VG-MineCraftServer/VG-MineCraftServer.qcow2 \
 --hostname VG-MineCraftServer \
 --arch amd64 \
 --mem 36864 \
 --cpus 12 \
 --user xxxxxx \
 --pass xxxxxx \
 --bridge br0 \
 --ip 172.16.5.27 \
 --mask 255.255.255.0 \
 --net 172.16.5.0 \
 --bcast 172.16.5.255 \
 --gw 172.16.5.1 \
 --dns 172.16.5.2 8.8.8.8 \
 --components main,universe \
 --addpkg acpid \
 --addpkg openssh-server \
 --addpkg nfs-common \
 --addpkg linux-image-generic \
 --addpkg postfix \
 --addpkg mailutils \
 --addpkg libsasl2-2 \
 --addpkg ca-certificates \
 --addpkg libsasl2-modules \
 --addpkg htop \
 --addpkg stress \
 --addpkg screen \
 --addpkg default-jdk \
 --rootsize=100000 \
 --libvirt qemu:///system ;
```

With that code, I get the following error immediately:

```
2016-12-17 00:39:13,998 INFO    : logging to file: /tmp/tmpDLxQiG
2016-12-17 00:39:14,022 ERROR   : /mnt/Storage/Virtual_Machines/VG-MineCraftServer/VG-MineCraftServer.qcow2 already exists
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-vm-builder", line 24, in <module>
    uvb.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMBuilder/contrib/cli.py", line 174, in main
    raise VMBuilderUserError('%s already exists' % destdir)
VMBuilder.exception.VMBuilderUserError: /mnt/Storage/Virtual_Machines/VG-MineCraftServer/VG-MineCraftServer.qcow2 already exists
root@VH-Ziggidy:/usr/bin#
```

There is NOTHING in that directory, so not sure what the deal is there....

If I CHANGE the .qcow2 file name for destination, it TRIES to set up the VM, it runs the install for about 8-10 minutes, and just before it completes, I get this error, but I don't get a prompt, it just immediately rolls back to command line.

```
Configuration file '/etc/sudoers'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** sudoers (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? dpkg: error processing package sudo (--configure):
 EOF on stdin at conffile prompt
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sudo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am at a total loss here and am not sure at ALL how to proceed, HELP!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I JUST NOTICED, that I am a complete MORON for the first portion of the issue....

mnt/Storage/Virtual_Machines was the directory which had the VM's running off of the Raidz2 array, 6x 4TB HDD's 5400 rpm. I added a 128 Gig SSD for this specific VM because it is for a game that reads and writes alot, so I moved the VM over to the SSD. I left the old one there as a backup, and apparently forgot to go in and move it.

Didn't notice the difference in the command I copied and pasted, as it was the difference of

/mnt/Storage/Virtual_Machines/VG-MineCraftServer/
/mnt/Virtual_Machines/VG-MineCraftServer/

SO, that leaves me with the issue of the sudoers file, but I will mark this as solved, as I have another question SPECIFICALLY on the sudoers issue...